# Can I slice a flex cable to reduce its width?

Tags: cables, ribbon-cable, flexible

I have a cable for my raspberry Pi camera that is bulky in its current wide state. While tricky, is there any downside to slicing it length wise, and stacking the pieces on top of each other? Would there be too much interference?

I also have a thicker cable that feeds a display that I would like to make narrower (see picture)

[image: Raspberry Pi cable]
[image: LCD screen cable]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can separate two parts of the ribbon cable relatively easy. You could just fold it in half too. If you separate them there may be interference if you separate a high frequency signal from its matching ground wire, or if you put the wrong one on top of each other. But this is highly dependent on the application of the wire. It wouldn't hurt to test it out.

Comment: Thanks. I'll play around with another length just in case.